# How can I solve the error 'expected expression'?

Tags: c++, struct, g++

The C++ code that gets an error is below. My g++ version is clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)

(The code is written by others many years ago, and may because of the version updates of the g++, I can not run it successfully now. )

```c
typedef struct Cond{
  int offset1; 
  bool (*comparator) (void * , void *, AttrType, int); 
  bool isValue;
  void* data; 
  int offset2; 
  int length; 
  int length2; 
  AttrType type; 
} Cond;

Cond *condList;

// Malloc the list of conditions to be met
condList = (Cond *)malloc(numConds * sizeof(Cond));
for(int i= 0; i < numConds; i++){
  condList[i] = {0, NULL, true, NULL, 0, 0, INT};
}
```

Compiler return an error in the line `condList[i] = {0, NULL, true, NULL, 0, 0, INT}` ,

```
ql_nodejoin.cc:78:19: error: expected expression
    condList[i] = {0, NULL, true, NULL, 0, 0, INT};
                  ^
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What C++ mode (version) are you compiling in?

Comment: Tip: Don't use `malloc` in C++. Don't even use `new`. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @tadman Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)

Comment: Half of your declarations are missing, so I'm not sure f you've declared `condList` earlier. If not, that's the error and make it something like `Cond* condList`

Comment: You're missing one parameter in your initialization. The list has 7 entries, but `struct Cond` has 8 members.

Comment: @Detonar Ohh yes

Comment: Don't forget to include the standard like `-std=c++17` when compiling.

Comment: @tadman yes, thank you!

Comment: @Detonar Strangly I got no error with only 7 entries in the list. I don't know why.

Comment: `condList` is not declared. I suppose it is just `Cond* condList;`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think it is the declaration problem. I solve the error in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279896/10606134

Comment: huh? Thats a link to your answer where `condList` isnt declared as well. In your real code you must have a declaration of `condList`, otherwise you would get a different error

Comment: what i mean is this: https://godbolt.org/z/11nG69899

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ohh I find condList is declared in another file. Cond *condList; sorry about not mentioning this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick fix is to add `-std=c++17` to support this C++ feature.

The actual fix is to use C++ more effectively, like employing a `std::vector` plus using [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to create entries as necessary:

```cpp
// Malloc the list of conditions to be met
std::vector<Cond> condList;

for (int i= 0; i < numConds; ++i) {
  condList.emplace_back(
    0, // int offset1
    nullptr, // bool (*comparator) (void * , void *, AttrType, int); 
    true, // bool isValue;
    nullptr, // void* data; 
    0, // int offset2; 
    0, // int length; 
    0, // int length2; 
    INT // AttrType type; 
  );
}
```

It behaves a lot like a regular array, you can still `condList[i]` and whatever.

This would be a lot easier with a default constructor:

```cpp
struct Cond {
  Cond() : offset1(0), comparator(nullptr), offset2(0), length(0), length2(0), type(INT) { };

  // ... (properties) ...
}
```

Where now you can just `emplace_back()` with nothing which sets defaults, or even easier, just pre-size the vector:

```cpp
std::vector<Cond> condList(numConds);
```

> Note: `typedef` isn't necessary in C++ as it is in C, as `struct` is not required.

Comment: So should I add the -std=c++17 as a flag in compile command? Like g++ -g -O1 -Wall -w -std=c++17 ......

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found condList is declared as "Cond *condList" in a .h file. Sorry about not mentioning this in the beginning. I usually use Python so ... I forget the rules of C++

Comment: The goal in modern C++ is to avoid using pointers as these come with a lot of responsibility that you should only assume when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by change the line

```
condList[i] = {0, NULL, true, NULL, 0, 0, INT};
```

to

```
Cond c = {0, NULL, true, NULL, 0, 0, INT};
condList[i] = c;
```

A small change. I think the type declaration is required.